# Aws backend code debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging, amazon-web-services, backend, dropwizard

I deployed my backend code(used framework is drop-wizard) in the form of jar file on AWS(Amazon Web service) server. I want to know is it possible to debug that jar file(jar file deployed on the AWS server) using eclipse on my local pc?? If yes than please display the way of how to do it?? 
Looking for a good response 
Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible if you open up the appropriate ports on your server. You should be able to search for "java remote debugging" and find the necessary info.

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to start your application with remote debugging
enabled.  With dropwizard, you are typically starting the application
on a server with:

```
java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Change this to:

```
java -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9999,server=y,suspend=n -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This sets up Java to listen for remote debugging sessions on port
9999.  Make sure you choose a port that's not blocked by firewalls or
your AWS security configuration.

Next, you have to configure Eclipse to connect to the remote
application for debugging.  In Eclipse, right click on the project and
select Debug, Debug Configuration.  Create a new configuration of
Remote Java Application.  Set the host to your AWS server and the port
to 9999, as above.

Now you should be able to set a breakpoint in your code and start a
debug session on the remote server.